# How to have code inside of a guard else statement in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
@IBAction func loginTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let error = validateFieldsSignIn()
    if error != nil {
        showErrorSignIn(error!)
    } else {
        guard let emailsignin = emailSignIn?.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines), 
            let passwordsignin = passwordSignIn?.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) else  {
            return showErrorSignIn("Fill in all fields")
        }
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailsignin, password: passwordsignin) { (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("There was an error")
                self.errorLabel3.text = "Invalid username or password"
                self.errorLabel3.alpha = 1
            } else {
                self.transitionToHome()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Although unless the fields aren't filled in the else statement gets triggered and the error label says fill in all fields, essential the code that is getting triggered is this:

```
else  {
    return showErrorSignIn("Fill in all fields")
}
```

I tried putting the Auth.auth().signIn() inside the else block although I got the following error:

```
Variable declared in 'guard' condition is not usable in its body
```

How do I fix this error message?

Comment: What is showErrorSignIn?  You are supposed to end the execution inside the guard.  Why are you trying to return a value?

Comment: "the fields aren't filled in the else statement gets triggered" Isn't the else supposed to be triggered when the fields aren't filled in? Do you mean "even if I fill in all the fields, the else still gets triggered"?

Comment: @ElTomato the show error sign in is a function which changes the error label and I am not trying to return a value but the only way I could declare the  `emailSignIn?.text!` and `passwordlSignIn?.text!` without getting an error was in a guard statement

Comment: @Sweeper yes that's is what is happening

Comment: @coder123 `emailSignIn` and `passwordSignIn` are probably nil. Are they outlets? Are they connected?

Comment: They are outlets and they are connected although how do I prevent them from being nil?