# Why is the text field.text showing up nil?

Tags: swift, xcode, null

I have the following code:

```
@IBAction func loginTapped(_ sender: Any) {
 guard
            let emailsignin = emailSignIn?.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines),
            let passwordsignin = passwordSignIn?.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
            else  {
                return showErrorSignIn("Error")
        }
}
```

I was getting errors so I added this code above:

```
print(emailSignIn?.text! as Any)
                    print(passwordSignIn?.text! as Any)
```

When I added this code I found that only the password would get printed to the console and the email would show up nil. The console would read:

```
nil
Optional("password1234")
```

My question is why is the email text always nil? The only thing I could think of is that they are on different different view controllers. Someone please help me figure out why email text field is always nil.

Comment: "they are on different different view controllers" And where did you declared `emailSignin`? Where is it "linked/connected/assigned/init?

Comment: Same as your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62766766/how-to-have-code-inside-of-a-guard-else-statement-in-swift ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62766766/how-to-have-code-inside-of-a-guard-else-statement-in-swift check this one

Comment: @Maya A valid answer was never given in that post

Comment: @Larme I declared `emailSignIn` and `passwordSignIn` both in view controller.swift although that is the class for both view controllers

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was because they were on different view controllers.